# Checking if any given string is a valid date

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know of any way to check if strings are valid dates? I'm trying to block against invalid dates, while not forcing any kind of date format. Basically here's the problem:

```
!!Date.parse('hello 1') === true
```

Javascript can figure out a date from that string, therefore, it's a date. I'd rather it not be. Anyone?

Comment: Look at moment.js. It is a javascript framework for these situations

Comment: I am using moment.js, it also thinks 'hello 1' is a date.

Comment: i searched Stack Overflow and found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13230360/string-date-to-javascript-date-parse-date

Comment: What don't you want to accept? Should "jan 1" be ok, or do you want to reject anything with letters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How close would stripping out spaces around words get you? It at least weeds out "hello 1" and such.

```
Date.parse('hello 1'.replace(/\s*([a-z]+)\s*/i, "$1")); // NaN
Date.parse('jan 1'.replace(/\s*([a-z]+)\s*/i, "$1")); // Valid
```

[update]
Ok, so we'll just replace any non-alphanumerics that fall between a letter and a number:

```
replace(/([a-z])\W+(\d)/ig, "$1$2")
```

Comment: Very close. The only thing this doesn't cover is checking the return value of `new Date()`. Using this logic, it says it's NaN.

Comment: I mean if we pass the return value of new Date(), it fails. So `Date.parse("Wed Feb 18 2015 17:59:11 GMT-0500 (EST)".replace(/\s*([a-z]+)\s*/i, "$1"))`

Comment: I upvoted this answer because it works in most situations and is good enough, but just wanted to point out it doesn't say text like the following is invalid: `Date.parse('Any words for Jane 1'.replace(/([a-z])\W+(\d)/ig, "$1$2")) == 978325200000`. It seems that just the end of the string has to be valid.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using moment.js, try using `parsingFlags()`:

```
var m = moment("hello 1", ["YYYY/MM/DD"]).parsingFlags();
if (!m.score && !m.empty) {
    // valid
}
```

It's the metrics used for `isValid()` and you can use them to make a stricter validation function.

**Note:** You can specify the other formats to support in the second argument's array.

Some other properties returned by `parsingFlags()` that might be of interest are the following:

- `m.unusedInput` - Ex. `["hello "]`
- `m.unusedTokens` - Ex. `["MM", "DD"]`

Comment: This forces me to know the date format, so won't work. However, awesome info about the parsingFlags stuff, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function to check `date`

```
  function isDate(s)
{   
  if (s.search(/^\d{1,2}[\/|\-|\.|_]\d{1,2}[\/|\-|\.|_]\d{4}/g) != 0)
     return false;
  s = s.replace(/[\-|\.|_]/g, "/"); 
  var dt = new Date(Date.parse(s)); 
  var arrDateParts = s.split("/");
     return (
         dt.getMonth() == arrDateParts[0]-1 &&
         dt.getDate() == arrDateParts[1] &&
         dt.getFullYear() == arrDateParts[2]
     );   
}

console.log(isDate("abc 1")); // Will give false
```

**Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/voidSO/kux0246j/1/)**

Comment: Sorry, running that console log returns true, not false.

Comment: This solution forces a date format with no spaces. In this case, using the return value of `new Date()` also returns false when passed into your function.

Comment: Try this time.. :P , Its full proof now... http://jsfiddle.net/voidSO/kux0246j/1/

Comment: Fool proof, unless you pass anything but a string into that function. Otherwise, yes, it seems to work. Still, feels very dirty. Will accept after I do a bit more digging.

Comment: This also excludes "jan 1" (for example). Should it?

Comment: Good point @RoyJ. I'd rather it didn't exclude that one, since it actually is a date.

Answer (score 0):

It would be ok if you check for several types of dates?

kind of this for narrow the permited dates:

```
if( givenDate.match(/\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d\d\d/)
|| givenDate.match(/\w*? \d{1,2} \d{4}/)
|| givenDate.match(anotherFormatToMatch) )
```

**UPDATED**

Or, althougt it restrict characters, you coud use something like this:

```
function myFunction() {
    var str = "The rain in SPAIN stays mainly in the plain"; 
    var date = new Date(str);
    if (date != "Invalid Date" && !isNaN(new Date(date) && !str.match(/a-z/g) )
        alert(date);
}
```

Comment: Your first solution restricts the date formats, and the second doesn't solve the core issue. `new Date("hello 1")` is a valid date.

Comment: Yes i see it, I have done a correction, could you give it a try please?

Comment: Forget it, it still has problems. I'll tell you when I get it working